# Limit of sequence of continued fractions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continued-fractions

Using fixed point theorem evaluate limit of sequence of continued fractions: $$2,\quad  2+\dfrac{1}{2},\quad 2+\dfrac{1}{2 + \dfrac{1}{2}}, \cdots$$

How to prove it?

Comment: Hint: $a_{n+1} = 2+\frac{1}{a_n}$.

Comment: Hint 2: so define $f(x) = 2 + \frac{1}{x}$ and see if it a contraction around $x=2$

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, Right. This function is contraction on $[2,+\infty)$ which is complete hence it has fixed point, namely $a$, i.e. $f(a)=a$. But why this point is limit of our sequence?

Comment: Look at the proof of the fixed point theorem: pick any $a \in X$ (the domain/range) and iterate $f(a), f(f((a)),\ldots$. The proof shows that this sequence always converges to the unique fixed point of $f$. Compute the fixed point of $f$....

Comment: @HennoBrandsma. Thank you very much for help! So taking $x_1=2$ and $f(x)=2+\frac{1}{x}$ and we get iteration $x_1, f(x_1), f(f(x_1)),\dots$ since $f$ is contraction hence this sequence has unique fixed point which can be found from $f(a)=a$ or $2+\frac{1}{a}=a$. Right?

Comment: Better: this sequence has a *limit*, which is the unique fixed point of $f$. Correct otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the other answer you need to prove that $f(x)=2+\frac 1 x$ is a contraction in order to use the fixed point theorem.

$$f'(x) = - \frac 1 {x^2}$$

The mean value theorem says

$$\left| \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} \right| = |f'(x_0)| \text{ for some } x_0 \in [a,b]$$

We know that $|f'(x_0)| = \frac 1 {x^2} < 1 \iff |x_0|>1$ This means $f$ is a contraction in $(-\infty,1)$ as well as in $(1,\infty)$, because we can use $|f'(x_0)| =: K$ as our constant $K$ that we need for the contration property (if $x_0$ is in one of these intervals), with this choice we have the contraction property:

$$|f(b)-f(a)| \leq K|b-a|$$ which is what we need.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that the sequence has a limit. Let it be $S$. Then

$$S=2+\frac{1}{S}$$

$$S^2=2S+1$$

$$S^2-2S-1=0$$

We use the quadratic formula:

$$S = \frac{2\pm \sqrt{8}}{2}$$

We discard the negative solution, so

$$S = 1 + \sqrt{2}$$

Comment: Note that this solution assumes that the sequence does converge. Proving that is necessary for a complete solution.

Comment: The OP asked for a use of the fixed point theorem.